# How to split a unknown sized list in different lines

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that will output me a list of cities as string, how would I split this list and paste each line in a different cell knowing that the number of lines in this list is unknown

Exemple of List

`Formosa, Brazil (193 km)
Sao Luis De Montes Belos, Brazil (190 km)
Palmeiras De Goias, Brazil (190 km)`

This could be more than only 3 cities, this is a segment of my code so far:

`output = driver.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""EchoTopic""]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody/tr").Text
Worksheets("Cityfinder").Cells(p, 5) = output`

This would return the list, it could be all the way from 1 to 30+ cities, the idea is to not paste the list but on each separate `p` row a different line of the list

Comment: To split it, just use the [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx) function and then use a [loop](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1873/flow-control-structures#t=201607221517521317619) to place everything where it should be

Comment: yes, but how do I know how many time I would have to loop? the size of the list is unknown

Comment: [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/95b8f22f(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what @litelite mentioned using split - the split takes care of how many to build into the array:

```
Sub splitandUbound()

    Dim s() As String, s1 As String
    Dim i As Integer

    s1 = "C:\_KTemp\TEMP\Test Macro for FolderExists\test\test1\test2\test3"

    ' Create the array
    s = Split(s1, "\")

    ' fill the array
    For i = 0 To UBound(s)
        debug.print Trim(s(i))
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @litelite  Thank you! I fixed it.